# Average Speed Calculation returns 'infinity'

Tags: java, math

On my android google map application I'm trying to calculate the average speed by taking the time (in milliseconds) and distance (in meters) and performing the next calculation on it:

```
private double avgSpeed = 0;
public void calcAvgSpeed(double distance, long time) {
    distance = distance / 1000;      //1000 = km
    time = time / 3600000;           // 1000 = sec, 60000 = min, 3600000 = hrs
    avgSpeed = (double) (distance / time);
}
```

to make sure it works i ran it with `calcAvgSpeed(300, 30000);` in which 300 is 300 meters and 30000 is 30000ms(or 30sec). Calculations I made say that avgSpeed should be 36 after the method. But when I print the result it says 'infinity' as if I'm dividing by zero..

Does anybody see if my method is wrong or why I get this weird answer?

Comment: You're doing integer division that results in 0, then dividing by the result.

Comment: Writing the result to a variable avgSpeed is bad design.  The function should return the average speed, if the caller wants to save it somewhere it can.  Side effects like this are considered bad because they're hidden from someone reading your code and debugging it.  There's no reason to expect that this function would change a variable.

Comment: To extend @GabeSechan tip, just make a function that `return a double` instead of void and outside the method write `private double avgSpeed= calcAvgSpeed(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeeed dividing by zero.

```
time = time / 3600000;
```

performs an integer division since `time` is of type `long`.

To fix this use something like

```
avgSpeed = distance * 3600000 / time;
```

Comment: Damn, thanks.. can't believe I actually made that mistake..
Implemented and tested your way of calculating it.
Since time is in milliseconds and distance is in meters the calculation to km/h would be avgSpeed = distance * 3600 / time; but I guess I didn't emphasize my need of these units enough.
Thank you very much, kind sir!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public void calcAvgSpeed(double distance, long time) {
```

to

```
public void calcAvgSpeed(double distance, double time) {
```

Since long is an integer, if you divide a long by 3600000, you'll get 0 (because it's rounded to the integer part).
And here you get a Division By Zero:

```
avgSpeed = (double) (distance / time);
```

Which is infinite

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this formula from this [LINK](http://www.cscprogrammingtutorials.com/2015/11/program-to-calculate-average-speed-in-miles.html):

```
/**
 *
 * @Author: Aghatise Osazuwa
 * Website: www.cscprogrammingtutorials.com
 *
 * Exercise 1.10 - Average Speed In Miles
 *
 */

public class Ex1_10 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Distance = 14km \nTime = 45 minutes 30 seconds = (45 x 60) + 30 \n"
    + "                               -------------- hours \n"
    + "                                    3600            \n"
    + "1 mile = 1.6 kilometers. \nAverage Speed in miles per hour = "
    + (14.0 / 1.6)/ (((45.0 * 60.0) + 30.0) / 3600) + " mph.");
  }
}
```

[image]

Or you can use :

```
    km * 3600
------------------  =  Average time kmh
   millisecond
```